# Azure web app sporadically throws CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, identityserver4

I have a `Identity Server` web app hosted on Azure. It has a `.pfx` file in it's root directory for signing. The problem is that when newly published it works perfectly fine but after some time it starts throwing `CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist.`

Based on [CryptographicException KeySet does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666483/cryptographicexception-keyset-does-not-exists) I would assume that it is a file access issue, but why out of the sudden azure is messing up with file access.

Comment: I have similar issue. My guess is that it might be connected to Data Protection keys, but not sure yet.

Answer (score 3):

I've been seing the same exception sporadically. In my case, it was caused by Data Protection keys changing when I swap between deployment slots. When using `services.AddDataProtection()` with the default configuration and hosting the app on Azure App Service, the data protection keys are stored in `%HOME%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-keys`. This directory is backed by a network share to make sure the keys are available on all your app instances, **BUT** this is not the case for deployment slots. So when you switch from one deployment slot to another, the keys will change and you will see `CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist` when your app tries to unprotect a payload.

To make sure your app is always using the same key, **you need to configure a different key storage provider**. I.e. use Redis or Azure Blob Storage as backing store.

You can find more information about how to configure this in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers).

I've also described the issue I had on [my blog](http://blog.stoverud.no/posts/asp-net-core-dataprotection-and-azure-web-apps/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you do not retrieve your signing cert from disk firstly. Rather upload the certificate to the associated web app in Azure Portal.

and retrieve the certificate on application startup

something like.

```
X509Certificate2 Certificate = null;
var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,"CERTIFICATE_THUMBPRINT_HERE",false);
Certificate = certCollection[0];
```